# Can't add AllowDrop, CanDragItems, CanReorderItems properties to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, xaml, gridview

As an exercise i'm trying to make a basic explorer.

I have already succeeded in dropping files and or (multiple) folders into my explorer but would like to be able to drag and drop in the GridView.
Mainly to reorder or drag files into folders that are in the view.

On several searches, i found that, to start, i should ad the following properties to my GridView:

```
CanReorderItems="True"
AllowDrop="True"
CanDragItems="True"
```

but VS gives me the following error:

*The property 'CanDragItems' was not found in type 'GridView'.*

I have seen multiple examples with these properties added to GridView.
I must be missing something obvious here.

My **XAML** code is the following:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title=""
        Height="350"
        Width="525"
        MinHeight="200"
        MinWidth="200">
    <Grid>
        <Grid   AllowDrop="True"
                Drop="Grid_Drop">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="26" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ToolBar Grid.Row="0"
                     Grid.Column="0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                     Name="toolBar1"
                     VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Name="btnFolderUp"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Click="btnFolderUp_Click">
                    <Image Source="images\folder-up.png" />
                </Button>
                <Button  HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                         Name="btnFolderNew"
                         VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                         Click="btnFolderNew_Click">
                    <Image Source="images\folder-new.png" />
                </Button>
            </ToolBar>
            <ListView Grid.Row="1"
                      Grid.Column="0"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                      VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                      Name="lvDataBinding"
                      MouseDoubleClick="lvDataBinding_MouseDoubleClick">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView CanReorderItems="True"
                              AllowDrop="True"
                              CanDragItems="True">
                        <GridView.Columns>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Name"
                                                      Name="Name"
                                                      Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click" />
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Image Source="{Binding Path=fileIcon}"
                                                   Margin="3,3,3,3"
                                                   Width="15"
                                                   Height="15" />
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                            <GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumnHeader Content="DateCreated"
                                                      Name="DateCreated"
                                                      Click="GridViewColumnHeader_Click" />
                                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DateCreated}"
                                                       HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                                       VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </GridViewColumn>
                        </GridView.Columns>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: I have seen in some places that the CanReorderItems property may be for windows 8 an higher only.
This wouldn't explain why the AllowDrop isn't working though.

Comment: CanDragItems is also Windows8+

Comment: I'm now aware of that. However, AllowDrop shows the same error. Could it be because i already have an allowdrop higher in the tree?

Comment: AllowDrop, canReorder and CanDragItems are not members of a GridView, isn't it? https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I would like to see your reference

Comment: I believe these are the links from msdn https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.candragitems and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.listviewbase.canreorderitems.Aspx

I must admit i lost track of theis question since i changed over to a gridview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question is WPF related.
So only AllowDrop="true" exists on the ListView.

In order to support Drag and Drop :

1. The style of the ListView Items has to be changed :

   ```
      <Window.Resources>
       <Style x:Key="ListViewItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
           <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.DragOver" Handler="ListBoxItemDragOver"/>
           <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.Drop" Handler="ListBoxItemDrop"/>
           <EventSetter Event="ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseMove" Handler="ListBoxItemPreviewMouseMove"/>
       </Style>
   </Window.Resources>
   ```

In the ListView declaration, reference to the style :

```
        <ListView AllowDrop="True"
                  ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemStyle1}"
                  Name="lvDataBinding"
                  Drop="lvDataBinding_Drop"
                  DragOver="lvDataBinding_DragOver"
                  DragEnter="lvDataBinding_DragEnter">
```

2. The events of the ListViewItems have to be implemented :

   ```
   private FileData sourceFileData;
   private void ListBoxItemPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.LeftButton != MouseButtonState.Pressed)
           return;
       var listboxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
       if (listboxItem == null)
           return;
       sourceFileData = listboxItem.DataContext as FileData;
       if (sourceFileData == null)
           return;
       var data = new DataObject();
       data.SetData(sourceFileData);
       // provide some data for DnD in other applications (Word, ...)
       data.SetData(DataFormats.StringFormat, sourceFileData.ToString());
       DragDropEffects effect = DragDrop.DoDragDrop(listboxItem, data, DragDropEffects.Move | DragDropEffects.Copy);
   }
   private void ListBoxItemDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       // support application data source and explorer file
       if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(FileData)) && !e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
           return;
       var listBoxItem = sender as ListBoxItem;
       if (listBoxItem == null)
           return;
       var targetFile = listBoxItem.DataContext as FileData;
       if (targetFile != null)
       {
           int targetIndex = files.IndexOf(targetFile);
           int sourceIndex = files.IndexOf(sourceFileData);
           double y = e.GetPosition(listBoxItem).Y;
           bool insertAfter = y > listBoxItem.ActualHeight / 2;
           if (insertAfter)
           {
               targetIndex++;
           }
           if (sourceIndex > targetIndex)
           {
               if (sourceIndex != -1)
                   files.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
               files.Insert(targetIndex, sourceFileData);
           }
           else
           {
               files.Insert(targetIndex, sourceFileData);
               if (sourceIndex != -1)
                   files.RemoveAt(sourceIndex);
           }
       }
       e.Handled = true;
   }
   private void ListBoxItemDragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       Debug.WriteLine(e.Effects);
       if (!e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(FileData)) && !e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
       {
           e.Effects = DragDropEffects.None;
           e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Some events have to be implemented to allow DnD from outer applications like Explorer :

   ```
   private void lvDataBinding_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Handled = true;
   }
   private void lvDataBinding_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
       {
           String[] files =  e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as String[];
           // that version only supports drop of a file, but could be augmented
           FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(files[0]);
           sourceFileData = new FileData { DateCreated = fileInfo.CreationTime, Name = fileInfo.FullName };
           e.Handled = true;
       }
   }
   ```
4. All the code above is code of the window.
   But data could come from a viewmodel in a nice project.
   Here is initialisation of the data :

   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {

   ```
   private ObservableCollection<FileData> files;
   public MainWindow()
   {
       files = new ObservableCollection<FileData>(
       new DirectoryInfo(@"e:\temp")
           .EnumerateFiles()
           .Select(fi => new FileData { DateCreated = fi.CreationTime, Name = fi.FullName })
       );
       InitializeComponent();
       lvDataBinding.ItemsSource = files;
   }
   ```

Here is a working VS Solution showing the code :
http://1drv.ms/1FNsK7n

Regards

Comment: Useful, very useful. Vote up!

Answer (score 0):

The [WPF version of GridView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have those properties. But the [WinRT/Universal version](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview.aspx) does. The examples you saw may be referring to the WinRT version. Both versions have similar members, so it's very easy to confuse the two.

Comment: Thanks for answer, in my case I worked on a Windows Phone 8.1 project. The problem is that I used GridView.ItemsSource = MyVar; In this case MyVar is converted to a List<Object> so it can't be ordered. I had to replace this with a ObservableCollection<Object>